# amp-image-lightbox issue with cropped images

Tags: amp-html

I have an issue with amp-image-lightbox. My current image tags are pointing to a cropped image of the full sized image. On desktop, any cropped image when clicked gets displayed in the full size in lightbox. Is there a way of getting it to work the same way using amp-image-lightbox for AMP pages?

I managed to get it to work but i see the cropped image in the lightbox not the full sized image

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is possible with amp-image-lightbox. However, it's easy to achieve the same behavior with an amp-lightbox:

```
<amp-img class="cropped" 
           on="tap:my-lightbox"
           role="button"
           tabindex="0"
           src="https://unsplash.it/300/200"
           width="200" height="200"></amp-img>

  <amp-lightbox id="my-lightbox" layout="nodisplay">
    <div class="lightbox"
         on="tap:my-lightbox.close"
         role="button"
         tabindex="0">
      <div>
        <amp-img src="https://unsplash.it/300/200"
                 layout="responsive" 
                 width="300" 
                 height="200"></amp-img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </amp-lightbox>
```

...and here is the css:

```
 <style amp-custom>
    amp-img.cropped img {
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    amp-lightbox .lightbox {
      background: #333;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  </style>
```

[Full sample on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/vomalotoqa/edit?html,output)